# When filling Excel dates with Python they cannot be sorted correctly

Tags: python-3.x, excel, datetime

I have a python 3.9 script that I use to ask the user for information and dump it into an excel. One of the data that is requested from the user is a date, this must be shown in Excel in the first column in DD/MM/YYYY format. Below, I show you the simplified part of the code most relevant to this problem:

```
def obtain_user_info():         
    
    date = datetime.today()
    if input('Has it happened today?') != 'y':
        valid_date = False
        while not valid_date:
            date_str = input('Type the date (YYYY-MM-DD format): ')
            try:
                # Trying to convert the entered date into an object of type datetime
                date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
                valid_date = True
            except ValueError:
                # If a ValueError exception occurs, the date is invalid
                print ('Invalid date. Please enter a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format.')
    
    return date

def excel_update(date):   
    
    excel_date= date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
      
    new_row = [excel_date]
        
    # Append the new row to the first empty row after the last row with content
    for col, value in enumerate(new_row, start=1):
            cell = sheet.cell(row=empty_row, column=col, value=value)
            cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
            
            # Format date, time, and duration columns
            if col in [1, 5, 6]:
                cell.number_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY' if col == 1 else 'HH:MM:SS'
            elif col == 7:
                cell.number_format = 'hh:mm:ss'
    
    empty_row += 1  # Move to the next empty row
    
    wb.save(excel_file)
```

The script correctly writes the date in Excel in DD/MM/YYYY format. However, when sorting the column by dates, these are not recognized properly.

[image: Example]

You can see how the dates added by the script, those that belong to September, are not recognized correctly.

I have tried changing the format to DD-MM-YYYY but the same thing keeps happening.

Comment: Ensure your dates in Excel are actually dates and not text strings that look like dates. You can do this by using `ISTEXT` function referencing the dates that are being misclassified. *Note: The cell number format does not alter the data type, so checking that is not a good method to differentiate.*

Comment: What's the engine to manipulate Excel? openpyxl?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Exactly, when using ISTEXT it gives me TRUE even though the cell format is Date. How can I fix it in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I use openpyxl @taller_ExcelHome

Comment: Unfortunately, not familiar enough with `openpyxl` to advise with code changes. But, it is likely your user is entering dates as MDY vs DMY. One way to avoid this is to use some kind of form where the user enters the date/month/year separately. Have them confirm correct entry with an **unambiguous** date format (*eg a format that spells out the month and uses a four digit year*) before proceeding. The reason you need to fix it at data input stage is that you have no other way to tell if, when user entered `1/10/2023` if he really means `1-Oct` vs `10-Jan`

Comment: Or you could use a calendar control to enter the dates.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks! I solved it by using directly the object datetime.date() and not the function strftime("%d/%m/%Y"). Thanks for your help